# how to return not found status from spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have following spring controller code and want to return not found status if user is not found in database, how to do it?

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user?${id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 44):

JDK8 approach:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return Optional
            .ofNullable( userRepository.findOne(id) )
            .map( user -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(user) )          //200 OK
            .orElseGet( () -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build() );  //404 Not found
}
```

Comment: `ResponseEntity.notFound().build()` leads to the following warning (SpringWeb 4.3.1): `Bad return type in lambda expression: ResponseEntity<Void> cannot be converted to ResponseEntity<User>`

Comment: This worked for me, the user object can be replaced by null value: `return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);`

Comment: You can even use `ResponseEntity.ok(user)` to pass the user as the body of an OK response.

Answer (score 35):

Change your handler method to have a return type of [`ResponseEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html). You can then return appropriately

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    User user = ...;
    if (user != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Spring will use the same `HttpMessageConverter` objects to convert the `User` object as it does with `@ResponseBody`, except now you have more control over the status code and headers you want to return in the response.

Answer (score 26):

With the latest update you can just use

```
return ResponseEntity.of(Optional<user>);
```

The rest is handled by below code

```
    /**
     * A shortcut for creating a {@code ResponseEntity} with the given body
     * and the {@linkplain HttpStatus#OK OK} status, or an empty body and a
     * {@linkplain HttpStatus#NOT_FOUND NOT FOUND} status in case of a
     * {@linkplain Optional#empty()} parameter.
     * @return the created {@code ResponseEntity}
     * @since 5.1
     */
    public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> of(Optional<T> body) {
        Assert.notNull(body, "Body must not be null");
        return body.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElse(notFound().build());
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

> public static  ResponseEntity of(Optional body)
>
> A shortcut for creating a ResponseEntity with the given body and the OK status,  or an empty body and a NOT FOUND status in case of an Optional.empty()  parameter.

[image: Javadoc ResponseEntity]

```
@GetMapping(value = "/user/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable final Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.of(userRepository.findOne(id)));
}

public Optional<User> findOne(final Long id) {
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id", id);
    try {
        return Optional.of(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SELECT_USER_BY_ID, paramSource, new UserMapper()));
    } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

it could be shorter using Method Reference operator `::`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
   return Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findOne(id))
        .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
        .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Need use ResponseEntity or @ResponseStatus, or with "extends RuntimeException"

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> deleteEmployeeById(@RequestBody Employee employee) {

        Employee tmp = employeeService.deleteEmployeeById(employee);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(tmp, Objects.nonNull(tmp) ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

or

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="was Not Found")
```